# file size validation without a gem in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails.
How to validate the size of a file uploaded with file_field form without using paperclip, carrierwave or other gems in ruby on rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you will have to write a custom validation in your model (the model which has the file), as follow:

```
validate :image_size_conformance

private
def image_size_conformance
    errors[:image] << "should be less than 500KB" if image.size > <the max size you want>
  end
```

Note that the `:image` in `errors[:image]` should be the name you are calling your `image` column ( well, I guess this will naturally be `image`).

Also note that the validation example I have above only checks for the size. You can use it as a guide to write validation for any other property you want. Hope this helps...